# How can I change mysql port from 0 to 3306?

Tags: mysql

I find it hard to establish a link between JDBC and MySQL. I think one of the reasons is the mysql port. I checked the port with the statement: `show variables like 'port';` in mysql. And the response is:

```
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| port          | 0     |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)
```

My operating system is archlinux.
How can I change mysql port from 0 to 3306?

I have changed the port number in both /etc/my.cnf and /etc/mysql/my.cnf. But it didn't work.

Comment: What port did you use to connect to the DB when you executed show variables like 'port'? Look at your my.ini, usually located in /etc/mysql

Comment: 3306 is the default port. Why do you think your non-disclosed JDBC problems are related to having MySQL on a non-standard port?

Comment: How did you fixed it?

Comment: 'I find it hard' is not a problem description, and there is no actual [tag:jdbc] here. What is your *actual* problem? You can determine the port it is listening on from `my.cnf` and also via `netstat`.

Answer (score 17):

First of all check what `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'skip_networking';` if it reports skip_networking = On, your mysqld is started without networking support (which leads to an value of 0 in the port system variable).

If this is the case, you most likely have to check the init scripts for your mysqld, its most likely under `/etc/init.d/mysql`, search here for `--skip-networking` and comment out (delete) this part. After this procedure you have to restart your mysqld.

Normaly there is no need to set the port 3306 explicitly since 3306 is the default port for mjysqld to listen on.

Comment: I have "skip_networking" set to On, no idea why.    I can't see where to change it

Comment: @OneSolitaryNoob edit your `my.cnf` file and add the line `skip-networking = Off` to the `[mysqld]` section, then restart the server.

Answer (score 2):

On my ubuntu install, in /etc/mysql/my.cnf theres a line that says :

```
[mysqld]
port = 3306
<snip...>
```

Try changing this value accordingly and restarting mysql.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this value from mysql configuration file. Steps are:

- To go to related file: `sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`
- To search for related line:(for Win, Linux) `ctrl + w` , (for Mac) `cmd + w`

> port = 0

```
(look for twice for [client] and [mysqld] sections)
```

- Replace your new value

> ```
> port            = 3306
> ```

- Save and Exit

> ```
> ctrl + x , cmd + x
> y
> ```

- Restart service

> sudo service mysql restart

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your mysql config file, my.cnf in /etc/my.cnf and change the port to 3306. Then restart mysql.

Source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/change-default-mysql-port-under-linuxunix/

Edit:

This website might help you a bit more for your specific platform: 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MySQL#Configuration

It has a portion talking about copying over your my.cnf file:

> Copy your choice of config file:
>
> `# cp /usr/local/mysql/support-files/my-medium.cnf /usr/local/mysql/data/my.cnf`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the port number in the MySQL config file: my.cnf

Comment: Did you restart MySQL?
You might want to shut MySQL down, make the change, then re-start your service. If that doesn't work, then there is something else at play. Some other daemon that is changing the port number during or before startup.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I had forgotten that I started mysqld with the `--skip-networking` flag in order to reset the MySQL root password, like so:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

Run `ps aux | grep mysql` and you may see the process (or a pair of them) hanging around still. If so, kill it/them and then restart mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error in my MySQL8-community after I reset root's PWD by running mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES; can't help for that even adding skip-networking =OFF and adding port=3306 in my.cnf and restart still can't help. then I found this solution
```

1. check which files override my.cnf

   sudo grep -rnw '/etc/' -e 'skip-networking

> /etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service.d/override.conf:3:ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
> /etc/my.cnf:28:#skip-networking

2. remove the override.conf

   rm -rf /etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service.d/override.conf
3. mysqld.service changed on disk

   systemctl daemon-reload
4. restart MySQL

   systemctl restart mysqld

Answer (score 0):

```html
Two days of searching the internet for an error that drupal 10  gave me 

   

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
to find that i ve got to do this following the skip networking = off
with my.cnf 

 # Use default MacPorts settings
!include /opt/local/etc/mysql57/macports-default.cnf
~                                                      
and macports-default.cnf :

 # MacPorts default options
[mysqld]
# skip-networking so multiple mysql server ports can be loaded
# without each competing for port 3306.
skip-networking 

changed skip-networking = off

and everything done
thanks a lot
```

Answer (score -1):

allow remote connection fixed, didn't change  " GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';"
edit my.cnf /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
user            = mysql
basedir         = /usr
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
language        = /usr/share/mysql/English
bind-address    = 65.55.55.2
# your mysql server ip address should place in bind-address
# skip-networking
```

restart the mysql service