# Laravel 4 migration:install [PDOException]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to call `php artisan migrate:install` but I get this error

```
  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Here is my app/confing/database.php

```
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
        'database'  => 'randomp_dev',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => 'root',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'port'      => 8888
    ),
```

and here is my app/config/local/databse.php

```
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
        'database'  => 'randomp_dev',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => 'root',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'port'      => 8888
    ),
```

and when I change 127.0.0.1 to 'localhost', the error changes to this:

```
  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

I'm running on Mac.

Thank you for any suggestion what I should do.

Comment: is the file in app/config/local called databse.php as it should be database.php.

Comment: no it is database.php

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` and of course you need to make sure all data (user/password, port) are valid.

Comment: I have tried that too ant doesn't work. and user/password, port are 100% valid

Comment: @JakubKohout And what when you don't use artisan? Does for example phpmyadmin or Laravel application can connect to database server?

Comment: @JakubKohout Something must be wrong, you should in phpmyadmin run `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';` to make sure port is `8888`. Are you sure that password for `root` user is `root`? By default it's often empty

Comment: @JakubKohout You can try changing in config port to 0 then or look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979134/how-can-i-change-mysql-port-from-0-to-3306

Comment: Thank you very much for you help this will be the problem, but now I can't change --skip-networking... anyway thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command:

```
php artisan migrate:install --env=local
```

Comment: @JakubKohout try this solution here, http://laravel.io/forum/02-17-2014-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused

Answer (score 0):

do you have enable the extension pdo for mysql in the php.ini?

extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

The extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll are uncommented.

regards.