# How to change the port number when logging into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to upload some csv data into a local database. It keeps kicking out 2002 errors.

I was told to try signing in with

```
mysql -u root -e "SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';"
```

It came back with port with value 0.

Why did it happen?

How do I fix it?

I also want to set the port with mysqli but not sure how to do it in php.

$database = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "funkytown", "houston");

Comment: Check your `my.cnf` or equivalent to see what's set.

Comment: Port 0 seems unlikely, maybe that means to use the default port, which is 0.

Comment: It might also mean that it's not listening on a network port, only the Unix domain socket. Use `localhost` as the hostname.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979134/how-can-i-change-mysql-port-from-0-to-3306